# gem 'gon' - name error in Quotes#index, uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Gon, Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the gem 'gon' but run into the above error, stating;

```
namer error in Quotes#index

 Showing /Users/jamesbkemp/Code/QuoteEngine/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
```

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Gon

Any idea what the issue may be and or any suggestoins on alternative gems to make passing controller variables into javascript easier?

Thanks

application.html.erb, note line 5;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>QuoteEngine</title>
    <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>    
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <%= render "layouts/navbar" %>

        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
       <div class="alert  alert-info alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>

        <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

quotes_controller.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  # before_action :owners_only, only: [ :show, :edit, :index, :update, :destroy ]

  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    # @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @quote = current_user.quotes.new(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
        redirect_to quote_url(@quote), notice: 'Quote request created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    # @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
    gon.gon_quote_id = @quote.id
  end

  def index
    @quotes = current_user.quotes.all
  end

  def edit
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
    if @quote.update_attributes(quote_params)
      redirect_to quote_path(@quote)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find(params[:id])
    @quote.destroy
    redirect_to quotes_path
  end

private

  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:gla, :prev_cover, :co_name, :co_number, :postcode, :industry, :lives_overseas, 
                                  :scheme_start_date, :payment_frequency, :commission_level)
  end
end
```

_quote.rb partial;

```
    <% @quote = local_assigns[:quote] %>
<section id="quotes">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-success panel-quote link-panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>GLA</strong>
            </div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
             <p><strong>Quote ID; <%= @quote.id %></strong></p>
          </div>

          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td>Company name</td>
              <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Company number</td>
              <td><%= @quote.co_number %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Office postcode</td>
              <td><%= @quote.postcode %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Industry</td>
              <td><%= @quote.industry %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Previous cover</td>
              <td><%= @quote.prev_cover %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Lives overseas</td>
              <td><%= @quote.lives_overseas %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Scheme start date</td>
              <td><%= @quote.scheme_start_date %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Payment frequency</td>
              <td><%= @quote.payment_frequency %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Commission level</td>
              <td><%= @quote.commission_level %></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <%= render :partial => "quote", locals: {quote: quote} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have your code on Github or can you post your view and controller code that relates to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to help with your case since I'm also using gon in rails 5 and it's working

- after run bundle install,
- open app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  and put under tag body <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>

do some test with open your your controller and create gon data (for example below I gave you with 10 users data

```
gon.users = User.limit(10)
```

open your coffee and test with log

```
alert gon.users
```

and don't forget to restart your rails server command

Comment: Thanks #wijajayd. Very strange, I'm running the app on a different mac now and started with the `Gon:::Base::render_data` in bosy not head and it worked just fine, then i moved the line back up to head, as recommended in docs, and it worked fine also. Strange, I shall run in the original environment tomorrow morning and see if i have the same problem again.

Comment: if you already following guide correctly most common problem , is just restart the rails server